# Can an array be declared as a constant?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, constants

Is it possible to either:

1. Declare an array as a constant

   OR
2. Use a workaround to declare an array that is protected from adding, deleting or changing elements, and therefore functionally constant during the life of a macro?

Of course I could do this:

```
Const myConstant1 As Integer = 2
Const myConstant2 As Integer = 13
Const myConstant3 As Integer = 17
Const myConstant4 ...and so on
```

...but it loses the elegance of working with arrays.  I could also load the constants into an array, and reload them each time I use them, but any failure to reload the array with those constant values before use could expose the code to a "constant" value that has changed.

Any workable answer is welcome but the ideal answer is one that can be setup once and not require any changes/maintenance when other code is modified.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use a function to return the array and use the function as an array.

```
Function ContantArray()
    ContantArray = Array(2, 13, 17)
End Function
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Leveraging the fact that the syntax for function calls and array calls is identical/ambiguous... lovely! Should probably be `ConstantArray` though (typo!). (PS - that's evil!)

Comment: Whoops!! you need to add suggestive naming to the Rubberduck...lol

Comment: That is brilliant!

Comment: It will look like an array that was never dimmed?  Makes sense.  So maybe something like GetConstantArray_RateMultipliers?

Comment: I would avoid underscores in public members, but yeah something descriptive that starts with a verb. Otherwise it's just misleading (and evil!)

Comment: @ChrisB `getRateMultipliers` would be better.  `get` implies a function and the plural implies an array.

Comment: Brilliant _(and I had no idea that it is possible to run a For Loop in the Immediate window)_!

Comment: Came here to find out about constant arrays and discovered join() and Rubberduck!

Comment: I absolutely love this! And it works with two dimensional arrays too by setting the function the return an array of arrays which you can then query by ?ConstArray(0)(1) and UBound(ConstArray) returns the first dimension and UBound(ConstArray(1)) returns the second dimension for the second array.

Comment: Is there any performance issue comparing to normal Array?

Comment: I know this is old, but does this method perform slower then just setting each value as a const?

Comment: @GiovanniDiToro I just compared using a function as a constant array with just declaring the array in the sub. I performed some maths and functions with the array and looped the code 5 000 000 times. The result: Using a function as an array took 122 seconds, declaring the array in the sub took 3 seconds. So it's quite a lot slower. But in the right context it could work. Looping 500 times the difference is 0.0122 vs 0.0003.

Answer (score 10):

How about making it a function? Such as:

```
Public Function myConstant(ByVal idx As Integer) As Integer
    myConstant = Array(2, 13, 17, 23)(idx - 1)
End Function

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print myConstant(1)
    Debug.Print myConstant(2)
    Debug.Print myConstant(3)
    Debug.Print myConstant(4)
End Sub
```

Nobody can change it, resize it, or edit its content... Moreover, you can define your constants on just one line!

Answer (score 9):

If the specific VBA environment is Excel-VBA then a nice syntax is available from the Excel Application's Evaluate method which can be shortened to just square brackets.

Look at this

```
Sub XlSerialization1()
    Dim v
    v = [{1,2;"foo",4.5}]

    Debug.Assert v(1, 1) = 1
    Debug.Assert v(1, 2) = 2
    Debug.Assert v(2, 1) = "foo"
    Debug.Assert v(2, 2) = 4.5

    '* write all cells in one line
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Resize(2, 2).Value2 = v
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to this Excel VBA question. It should have the most votes and be the accepted answer.

Comment: I love this formula-style syntax! But, sadly, it can't be used for a constant `const x = [{1,2,3}]`

Answer (score 8):

I declared a `String` constant of `"1,2,3,4,5"` and then used `Split` to create a new array, like so:

```
Public Const myArray = "1,2,3,4,5"

Public Sub createArray()

        Dim i As Integer
        A = Split(myArray, ",")

        For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
                Debug.Print A(i)
        Next i

End Sub
```

When I tried to use `ReDim` or `ReDim Preserve` on `A` it did not let me. The downfall of this method is that you can still edit the values of the array, even if you can't change the size.

Comment: If you `Dim A() As String` you can `ReDim` or `ReDim Preserve` it later. This requires that you strongly type your `Const myArray As String = "1,2,3,4,5"`.

Comment: Genius solution to a problem I've had for years.  Thank you!!  I'm disappointed in myself for not thinking of it. :-(  Everyone suggests using a function instead of a const, but I want to be able to maintain my arrays like I can in C/C++ at design time.

Answer (score 3):

Can an array be declared as a constant? No.

Workarounds - Simplest one I can think of is to define a constant with delim and then use `Split` function to create an array.

```
Const myConstant = "2,13,17"

Sub Test()
    i = Split(myConstant, ",")

    For j = LBound(i) To UBound(i)
        Debug.Print i(j)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need a new instance each time you can use a `Static` local variable to avoid multiple objects creation and initialization:

```
Private Function MyConstants()
    Static constants As Variant

    If IsEmpty(constants) Then
        constants = Array(2, 13, 17)
    End If

    MyConstants = constants
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this too simplistic?

```
PUBLIC CONST MyArray = "1,2,3,4"
```

then later in a module:

```
Dim Arr as Variant

SET Arr = split(MyArray,",")
```

Comment: This simple solution works for me. Could also define Arr as a string array (Dim Arr() as string).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but these archives are often scanned for many years after being posted, so I don't see a problem with adding things long after the origin date.

How about creating a class, with a read-only property returning the 'array' value? You can specify a parameter using the same syntax as an array index, and defining only a GET property effectively makes it read-only. Define the constant values inside the class and it will work just like a constant array, even though the actual construction is different.

Answer (score 0):

No - arrays can't be declared as constant but you can use a workaround.

You can create a function that returns the array you want

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?1233-Solved-Declare-a-Constant-Array

Comment: If you had shown such a function in your answer, preferably using the sample data in the question, as well as linked to that thread, I would have given you an upvote ;)

Comment: It's not my work; it probably doesn't deserve an upvote :-). 30 seconds with google!

Answer (score 0):

Using above information, I came to following working solution for comparing short text information of a month, independent from Excel using German language:

Const MONATE = ",Jän,Feb,März,Apr,Mai,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Okt,Nov,Dez"

.. and later in the code:

```
    If StringToCompare = Split(MONATE, ",")(Month(dt)) Then
```

NOTE: as the Split-Array starts with index 0 I added the comma in the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know when this changed, but in Excel 365, this works (or, at least, does not generate a compiler error):

```
Const table1Defs As Variant = Array("value 1", 42, Range("A1:D20"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even without the Range reference, this does not work as recently as Office 2016 (mine is 32-bit) (tested with Excel, Outlook, and Access).

Comment: I'm On Office 365 (32 bit). Unfortunately this doesn't work.